# android get selected checkBox displayed in ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i am trying to make an app where i populate my listView with some products from an existing database, so far so good :)

Now i have a checkbox on each product row and when it's clicked i want to get a reference to that product.

I am new to this please help me. here is the code:

```
public class NewListPage extends MainAppPage {

    protected TextView productName;
    protected TextView productPrice;
    protected CheckBox checkBox;
    protected Database db;
    public ListView listView;
    public Context context;
    protected boolean isChecked;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.existing_product_listview);

        db = new Database(this);

        productName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_list_productName);
        productPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_list_productPrice);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.existing_product_listView);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.new_list_productChecked);

        populateListView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_main_saveItem) {

    /* WHEN I CLICK ON THE SAVE ITEM I WANT TO GET THE REFERENCE TO THE PRODUCT THAT IS CHECKED HERE*/

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void populateListView(){
        //get all rows from DB;
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllRows();

        // get the product from the product table & price from price table
        String[] from = new  String[]   {Database.PRODUCT,         Database.PRICE};
        int[] to = new int[]           {R.id.new_list_productName, R.id.new_list_productPrice};

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.new_list_page, cursor, from, to,0);


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.existing_product_listView);
        listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: write in xml  android:checked="true" or programatically checkBox.setChecked(true);

Comment: What you want actually?

Comment: When i click on the checkBox and afther i click on the save item from the toolbar (R.id.menu_main_saveItem) i want to get all the products that are checked and put them in a newList. The app is's a grocery list, with an exiting database

Answer (score 0):

OnCheck of the check box add your item details to ArrayList> arr_main=new ArrayList>();

with id as reference play around with the inserting and deleting of the product in arraylist.

And pass the final arraylist to another list view to populate the list view of selected item.

Comment: Can u please show me how exactly? I don,t have much experience with this. Asif Sb